# Reuse spring boot properties for liquibase configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I want to start use liquibase in my Spring Boot app. Now I already have db configuration, something like:

```
abc.datasource.jdbc-url=
abc.datasource.username=
abc.datasource.password=
```

For liquibase usage I also added the parameters to the same file with a same values:

```
spring.liquibase.url=
spring.liquibase.user=
spring.liquibase.password=
```

The question is: is it possible to configure it somehow to avoid duplication of the configuration values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it the same file declare shared properties and reference them below

```
shared.datasource.jdbc-url=
shared.datasource.username=
shared.datasource.password=

abc.datasource.jdbc-url=${shared.datasource.jdbc-url}
abc.datasource.username=${shared.datasource.username}
abc.datasource.password=${shared.datasource.password}

spring.liquibase.url=${shared.datasource.jdbc-url}
spring.liquibase.user=${shared.datasource.username}
spring.liquibase.password=${shared.datasource.password}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access defined properties in `application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: application-name
some-value: ${spring.application.name} # will be equal to 'application-name'
```

The order of the properties is not important.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do not need to repeat the same parameters, as those will be automatically picked up for Liquibase.

See example here:
https://github.com/juliuskrah/spring-boot-liquibase/blob/main/src/main/resources/application.properties

Comment: I have multiple datasources in application properties and I need to apply liquibase only to one of them.